# References for the name of that theorem linked with the IVT?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Here is the theorem :

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for all compact set of the form $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f([a,b])$ is again a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ and such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous.

It is a sort of converse for the IVT and it can be proved using nested sets and compactness. Then I searched for the name of that theorem and find nothing really precise. Apparently it could come from Howe in $1926$ but I could not find any informations about it...

If someone has references about it, it would be great to share !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is the intermediate value theorem which says that the image of an interval by a continuous function is again an interval.

Comment: Thank you, Maman